# NullPointerException parsing JSON object

Tags: java, php, blackberry

I'm getting an exception from my code below:

```
int[] startApps;
JSONObject jsonObjectMapData=new JSONObject(result); 
JSONArray jsonaryPlaceMark = jsonObjectMapData.getJSONArray("Apps"); 
JSONObject apps=   jsonaryPlaceMark.getJSONObject(0); int indx=0; 
startApps[indx++]=Integer.parseInt(apps.getString("Thread1")); 
startApps[indx++]=Integer.parseInt(apps.getString("Thread2"));
```

I get java.lang.NullPointerException on line:

```
          startApps[indx++]=Integer.parseInt(apps.getString("Thread1"));
```

Server Response:

```
{
 "name": "10.000000,106.000000",
"Status": {
"code": 200,
"request": "geocode"
},
"Apps": [ {
"Thread1": 1,
"Thread2": 1,   
"Thread3": 1,
"Thread4": 1,
"Thread5": 1,
"Thread6": 1,
"Thread7": 1
} ]
}
```

Comment: show the json string?

Comment: What is `startApps`?  It's not declared in the code you show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't initialize your array.

Try:

```
int[] startApps;
startApps = int[10]; // or however big it needs to be
```

Or do it one step:

```
int[] startApps = int[10];
```